# simple require.extensions example not working

Tags: javascript, node.js

module.extensions doesnt seems to be working properly, the example given on http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_require_extensions returns nothing.

I m using node@0.8.12 | linux | ia32

node js file (run.js):

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
fs = require('fs');

    require.extensions['.jse'] = function(module, filename) {
      var content = fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf8');
      module.exports = content;
    };

require('./0.jse')

// 
console.log(require('./0.jse'))
```

jse file (0.jse):

```
#! /usr/bin/env node
console.log('IT WORKS!')
```

$ ls -al *.jse *.js

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 alvaro alvaro  46 dic  6 17:26 0.jse
-rwxr-xr-x 1 alvaro alvaro 314 dic  6 17:32 run.js
```

file --mime *.js *.jse

```
run.js: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
0.jse:  text/plain; charset=us-ascii
```

$ node run.js

it outputs:

```
#! /usr/bin/env node
console.log('IT WORKS!')
```

instead of:

```
IT WORKS!
```

whats wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ended compiling with module._compile(contents, filename).

so, node js file (run.js):

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
fs = require('fs');

    require.extensions['.jse'] = function(module, filename) {
      var content = fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf8');
      return module._compile(content, filename);
    };

require('./0.jse')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning `module`, see below

```
require.extensions['.jse'] = function(module, filename) {
   var content = fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf8');
   module.exports = content;
   return module; // Return module
};
```